# Need one more wall in this cube

Tags: css, user-interface

I am not a CSS developer so please bear with me..
This is what am trying to achieve.. [image]

As of now i am able to create this much..

[image]

I am now confused how to create the wall (C). Please help me.

Code as of now for the 2d pic is as follows.

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
#floor {
-webkit-transform: skew(148deg); 
-moz-transform: skew(148deg); 
-o-transform: skew(148deg); 
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000066;
    float: left;
    height: 54px;
    left: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 108px;
    width: 100px;
}
#frontwall {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: #0099FF;
    position: fixed;
    left: 117px;
}
#otherwall {
    width: 150px; 
    height: 100px; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) ; 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg) ; 
    -o-transform: rotate(-20deg) ; 
    background: #0000CC;
    float: left;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="otherwall"></div>
<div id="frontwall"></div>
<div id="floor"></div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skew the X and Y independently, which is probably what you want to do. The following [works for me in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/cB9rj/).

Note that skew is not well-supported by slightly older browsers (e.g. IE8) and that the results you'll get for lining things up to the pixel may vary slightly across browsers anyway.

I think that everything that [supports skew](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) properly also [supports SVG,](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg) and that would be a *much* better way of doing this (the co-ordinates would be much more obvious).

SVG simplicity:

```
<html>
<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="150px" height="125px">
        <polygon points="50,0 50,100 150,100 150,0" style="fill: #0099FF"/>
        <polygon points="0,25 50,0 50,100 0,125" style="fill: #0000CC"/>
        <polygon points="0,125 100,125 150,100 50,100" style="fill: #000066"/>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Skew craziness:

```
<style type="text/css">
#floor {
    -webkit-transform: skewx(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: skewx(-45deg);
    -o-transform: skewx(-45deg);
    transform: skewx(-45deg);
    background: #000066;
    height: 50px;
    left: 35px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 108px;
    width: 100px;
}
#frontwall {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: #0099FF;
    position: fixed;
    top: 8px;
    left: 60px;
}
#otherwall {
    left: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 33px;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transform: skewy(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: skewy(-45deg);
    -o-transform: skewy(-45deg);
    transform: skewy(-45deg);
    background: #0000CC;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="otherwall"></div>
<div id="frontwall"></div>
<div id="floor"></div>
</body></html>​
```

Comment: Thanks... SkewY is what i was looking into.. This is something dynamic and will be handled from back-end so needs to be generated dynamically.. so didn't went with image solution. Thanks again Alastair

Comment: You can generate your SVG dynamically. I've updated my answer to show you the better way of doing this.

Comment: WOW! I never had any idea about that... so simple.. will be using your new SVG solution.. Thanks again!

Comment: Just wondering... is there any software to map those points.. or how do you calculate? Do you do a small graph math before doing it or there is a easier way?

Comment: For the CSS skew stuff, I cheated by putting it at 45 deg and doing various ratios with sqrt(2). For the SVG stuff I just made up the coordinates (100 x 100 square with 25px offsets for the other walls). Note that if you want to do real 3D cubes, etc. then you can do that with WebGL, although you'll need Chrome, Safari or Firefox for that.

Comment: Or you can use CSS 3D transforms: http://www.paulrhayes.com/2009-07/animated-css3-cube-interface-using-3d-transforms/